# have two users side by side in a members page

Tags: php

so I would like in my registered users page, or members page all my users on it (that's the easy part) where i'm having trouble is I would like to have 2 users side by side, and then on the next line 2 other users and so on.
Something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9iaV.jpg)

i'm using php and it's to use after a php query from mysql, this is my code at the moment:

```
<?php
    include '_database/database.php';
    session_start();
    $current_user = $_SESSION['user_username'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users order by user_id desc";
    $result = mysqli_query($database,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($database));
    while($rws = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
?>

    <table style="width: 200px;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td style="width: 100px;"><img src="userfiles/avatars/<?php echo $rws['user_avatar'];?>" width="100" height="100"></td>
            <td style="width: 200px;">
                <?php echo $rws['user_country'];?> <?php echo $rws['user_username'];?><br>
                <?php echo $rws['user_joindate'];?><br>
                1<br>
                2<br>
                3<br>
                See more
            </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
 <?php } ?>
```

Thank you !

Comment: bootstrap it; a lot easier

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. So - tell us what you've tried and what you observed happening. How would you like that to change? what have you researched? Have you tried using bootstrap?

Comment: How ? i'm a beginner in php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    include '_database/database.php';
    session_start();
    $current_user = $_SESSION['user_username'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users order by user_id desc";
    $result = mysqli_query($database,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($database));
?>

<div class="container" style="width: 200px;">
    <?php while($rw = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
        <div class="user" style="width: 100px; float: left;">
            <img src="userfiles/avatars/<?php echo $rw['user_avatar'];?>" width="100" height="100">
            <div class="userInfo">
                <?php echo $rw['user_country'] . ' ' . $rw['user_username'];?><br>
                <?php echo $rw['user_joindate'];?><br>
                <!--Content--><br>
                <!--Content--><br>
                <!--Content--><br>
                <a href="<!--Link-->">See more</a>
            </div>
       </div>
   <?php } ?>
</div>
```

- i haven't tested the code.

You also can use for design HTML, CSS and JS frameworks like Bootstrap

Comment: Thanks ! it's not working perfectly, but this is the closest that i've got, thanks very much !